# How to populate second dropdown based on ajax of first dropdown and get value from it in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Hi I have two dropdowns namely standard and section. When I select a standard, section dropdown should populate based on standard selection. And I want to get the value of the section dropdown. I have tried to do it in selenium webdriver. But I could not imagine how to achieve this as I am completely new to selenium webdriver. Please advise me if you have any ideas.

**Below is my code of what I achieved:**

```
@Test(dataProvider = "StudentDetails")
    public void createStudents(String studname, String email, String phone,
            String admissionno, String rollno, String standard, String section) {
        try
        {
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Students")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("student_student_name")).sendKeys(studname);
            driver.findElement(By.id("student_email")).sendKeys(email);
            driver.findElement(By.id("student_phone")).sendKeys(phone);
            driver.findElement(By.id("student_admission_no")).sendKeys(admissionno);
            driver.findElement(By.id("student_roll_no")).sendKeys(rollno);

            Select stand = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("standard_standard_id")));
            stand.selectByVisibleText(standard);
            Select sec = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("section_section_id")));
            sec.selectByVisibleText(section);
            driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();

        }catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

When I run this code, Standard could be visible in standard dropdown. But section could not be viewed as I used ajax call to onchange the dropdown based on standard selection. But I want the section value should be displayed in dropdown. How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to wait for some time for second dropdown to load its values. So put some wait once you select any value from standard dropbox.

```
   Select stand = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("standard_standard_id")));
                    stand.selectByVisibleText(standard);

    //wait for some time.....need to handle some wait condition

                Select sec = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("section_section_id")));
                sec.selectByVisibleText(section);
                driver.findElement(By.name("commit")).click();
```

Comment: Yeah exactly..I got the solution and fixed my issue. anyway thanks for your idea